# Can't switch theme in MacVim

Tags: macvim

I recently installed MacVim along with Janus. When I'm inside macVim I can change my color scheme with `:color freya` but if i restart MacVim the them is reverted back to ir_black. I've added freya to my .vimrc.local, but it doesn't help.

Also added the following: `set term=xterm-256color`

I'm using Lion and I've got a bunch of themes in ~/.vim/colors

Answer (score 1):

Are you sourcing your `.vimrc.local` by hand? That is not a standard file. MacVIM will read your `~/.vimrc` and `~/.gvimrc`. I'd suggest you keep your syntax settings in `.gvimrc` for MacVIM unless you want to use them in your terminal as well.

If you want to keep a generic `.gvimrc` that is shared by multiple systems and set your color only for this machine in `.gvimrc.local` you can put the following at the end of your `~/.gvimrc`

```
" Allow for local machine-specific modifications
if filereadable($HOME . "/.gvimrc.local")
  source ~/.gvimrc.local
endif
```

Comment: Sigh. The `*.local` is due to [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus). The typical Janus installation takes over a user’s `.vimrc`, `.gvimrc`, `.vim/`, and then expects users to put their customizations in `*.local` variant files. Ick.

Answer (score 1):

GUI-based instances of Vim source `.vimrc` and then `.gvimrc`, so anything in the latter can potentially override anything in the former.

The Janus `.vimrc` does a [`color desert`](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/vimrc#L122) and
its `.gvimrc` does a [`color ir_black`](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/gvimrc#L72).

Since `.vimrc.local` is sourced by Janus’s `.vimrc` as a final step, its settings can be (in this case, are being) overridden by Janus’s `.gvimrc`.

To override the `color ir_black` from Janus’s `.gvimrc`, you need to put your `color freya` in your `.gvimrc.local` (which Janus’s `.gvimrc` sources as a final step—if it exists and is readable).

Comment: I also had this problem - thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

MacVim is a graphical version of Vim, so it can have a graphical config file (`.gvimrc`) as well as the regular `.vimrc`.

Have you tried putting your color setting in `.gvimrc`, or seen whether it has a conflicting setting?